# RFID-RC522 not reading different card accept those card which is comes along with it

Tags: rfid

I got a RFID-RC522 along with two RFID cards. I am using Arduino and trying to read cards. I have successfully read those card which was along with RFID-RC522. But when I am trying to read different card means my friend's office card then nothing is happening.

Thank for your help...

Comment: Wasn't this reader only work with ISO 14443A tags? Maybe your friend's office card is not under this spec, or not even Mifare technology at all (eg HID cards). Try to read their card using an Android phone first.

Comment: Thank for your suggestion. Can you tell me please is there is a condition that RFID and RFID reader have any king of combination or any kind of tribes that they can communicate with each other only?

Comment: My guess - your friend's office card is NOT using Mifare technology (like my office access card), thus you cannot read it.  From the data sheet of RC522 (I've google MFRC522) it support most of the Mifare variants, but that's only with Mifare (ISO 14443 A). An old day access card technology: HID is still common (because you cannot copy and fake it using your Android phone)

Comment: thanks lot @KenCheung got it

Comment: Didn't think about using NFC on my phone for debugging faulty RFID cards. Great suggestion @KenCheung

Answer (score 2):

Simple Solution: **increment supply voltage, like 3.3 to 3.6V.**

I am also powering the reader with **4.8V** and it has been working without troubles since months. I was having the same issue as you, maybe it could read other cards eventually but no more than the ones that goes with the RC522 reader.

This is because some cards needs more energy to transmit the data to the anthem of the reader. When you increment the power, you can also arrive to other cards that maybe need a little power extra to transmit information.

Cards readed succesfully: Mifare 1K, Mifare Desfire, Credit Cards. (No more card types have been tried.)

Answer (score 0):

RC522 only works on 13.56MHz frequency, wich is the most common. Other frequencies can be used in RFID cards, I think this is the problem because RC522 should read other cards formats (even if not suported). If this was the case RC522 should be able to read the header of the card in wich is described the card type, but if thecard works in other frequency it shouldn't be able to read it at all.